# Adding Data to Request in Django REST Framework in Authentication Class

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-request

Suppose I have the following Authentication class in DRF. If the request is authenticated, then I need some additional data in the `request` object. Say, `REQUIRED_DATA` is that variable.

```
class MyAuthClass(BaseAuthentication):
    
    def authenticate(self, request):
        # suppose is_authenticated_request and authenticated_user are methods
        # which return the responses as described by their name
        if is_authenticated_request(request):
            user = authenticated_user(request)
            request.REQUIRED_DATA = some_variable_of_any_type
            return (user, None)
        raise exception.AuthenticationFailed(_('Authentication failed.'))
```

Here is how I used it in the viewset.

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    authentication_classes = [MyAuthClass]
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #############
        # ......... #
        request.REQUIRED_DATA # using variable
        # ......... #
        #############
```

Am I going right?

I need this variable after the request is authenticated. Is their a better way to do this? Middleware is one but Middleware runs for each request, I need for this viewset only.

Comment: What data supposed to be in your `request.REQUIRED_DATA`? Also, can you clarify what you are going to with `request.REQUIRED_DATA`?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu For my specific case, it's a string. Some sort of generated token. I need it fro different things in the successive methods executed in the viewset.

Comment: I think, you can attach the string to **user** instance instead of `request`. Example: **`user.foo = 'some-variable'`**

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Makes sense. Thanks.